# Accessing the main thread, How it works?

Tags: java, multithreading

consider the following code snippet

```
public class ThreadDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        t.setName("MainThread");
    }
}
```

I know that each class automatically **extends java.lang.Object**. and this class does not extend or implement any other class or interface.
my question is since the class ThreadDemo is **NOT extending or implementing** any interface or class including Thread and Runnable.
How it is possible for us to use the class *Thread* in the main method to access the main thread?
I mean how it works??? Is it something about the JVM stuff?

Comment: You questions doesnt make any sense to me. You are creating a thread object. How does creatng a object has anything to do with the class that creates that object? You could also create a list or an timestamp or whatever whithout having threaddemo class implementing or extending any interface/class.

Comment: WRONG, WRONG, WRONG!!! #ckruczek.   I am NOT creating an object. the statement 'Thread.currentThread();' give you access to the main thread which has been created by JVM **I AM NOT USING THE 'NEW' KEYWORD**

Comment: Don't mix up class and thread that is currently executing the class's code. The class is whatever class and the thread executing it is a Thread. Compare it to getting a Color like `Color c = Color.Blue` - same thing basically.

Comment: What ckruczek meant was that you create a reference. But the rest still is valid.

Comment: Hahaha nice try @kolahghermezi. You have to get aware of the basic programming concepts

Comment: @ckruczek  I am a beginner in OOP and Java. thanx any way...

Comment: Well, @kolahghermezi then you better dont offend people who might have more experience than you and want to help you

Comment: @ckruczek  I didn't mean that. sorry any way...

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the static `currentThread()` method of `Thread`, which returns the current thread (hence the name). Then you set its name.

There's nothing magical about this code (except that `currentThread()` is a native method).

Comment: BUT I did not create the main thread, I know that the JVM did that. how the JVM knows that I mean the main thread NOT any other thread???

Comment: @kolahghermezi Because you're on the main thread. If you were on a different thread, a different thread would be returned.

Comment: Because it is the thread that is currently executing the code.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor   NOW I GET IT ;-)

Comment: @kolahghermezi There is nothing to get really. A Thread - whichever - is executing your code. Thread.currentThread is also executing on that said thread. So it will return itself and that's it.

Comment: @kolahghermezi Google will give you more explanations than I can shake a stick at.

Answer (score 0):

> how the JVM knows that I mean the main thread NOT any other thread?

The name "currentThread" is a bit of a misnomer.  It dates back to a time when most computers had only one CPU, and so only one thread---the *current* thread---could be running at any given time.

On my laptop, there can be eight "current" threads, and on a big mainframe, there can be more than a hundred.  What `Thread.currentThread()` does these days is return the identity of whatever thread called the method.

Answer (score 0):

`currentThread( )` is a public static member of the `Thread` class. It's general form is:

```
static Thread currentThread( )
```

This method returns a reference to the thread in which it is called.

Static methods can be called without creating an instance of the class, using the class name as follows:

```
ClassName.staticMethod( )
```

Since `currentThread( )` is a static member method it is therefore used directly without creating an instance of the `Thread` class.